# What is right and full Frobenius canonical form?

Tags: state-space

I'm having a trouble here. I'm supposed to learn Frobenius canonical representation form for finding statespace matrices, but I found many different forms.

Let's suppose we have a system with this transfer function: $$H(s) = \frac {b_ns^n + b_{n-1}s^{n-1}+ \cdots + b_1s+b_0}{a_ns^n+a_{n-1}s^{s-1}+ \dots + a_1 s +a_0}$$

For this system I'm able to find matrices as:

$$A = \left| \matrix {0 & 1 & 0& \dots & 0\\0 & 0 &1&\dots&0\\ \vdots &&&& \vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&1\\-\frac{a_0}{a_n}&-\frac{a_1}{a_n}&-\frac{a_2}{a_n}&\cdots&-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}} \right|$$
$$B = \left| \matrix{0\\0\\\vdots\\\frac{1}{a_n}} \right|$$
$$C = \left|\matrix{b_0-\frac{a_0b_n}{a_n}&b_1-\frac{a_1b_n}{a_n}&\cdots&b_{n-1}-\frac{a_{n-1}b_n}{a_n}}\right|$$
$$D = \left|\matrix{\frac{b_n}{a_n}}\right|$$
Then matrices that look the same as this but $a_n$ is probably meant to be $1$, 'cause it's missing in every matrix. 
But also:
$$A = \left| \matrix {-a_{n-1} & -a_{n-2} & \cdots & -a_1 & -a_0\\1 & 0 &\dots & 0&0\\ 0&1&\cdots&0&0\\\vdots &&&& \vdots\\0&0&\cdots&1&0} \right|$$
$$B = \left| \matrix{1\\0\\\vdots\\0} \right|$$
$$C = \left|\matrix{1&0&\cdots &0}\right|$$
$$D = 0$$
or:
$$A = \left| \matrix {-a_{n-1} & -a_{n-2} & \cdots & -a_1 & -a_0\\1 & 0 &\dots & 0&0\\ 0&1&\cdots&0&0\\\vdots &&&& \vdots\\0&0&\cdots&1&0} \right|$$
$$B = \left| \matrix{1\\0\\\vdots\\0} \right|$$
$$C = \left|\matrix{(b_{n-1}-b_na_{n-1})&(b_{n-2}-b_na_{n-2})&\cdots &(b_0-b_na_0)}\right|$$
$$D = \left|\matrix{b_n}\right|$$

Somewhere it's shown as for 
$$H(s) = \frac {b_ms^m + b_{m-1}s^{m-1}+ \cdots + b_1s+b_0}{a_ns^n+a_{n-1}s^{s-1}+ \dots + a_1 s +a_0}$$ 
and  is wrote that $$D = \left|\matrix{\frac{b_m}{a_n}}\right|$$
without denote what exactly these indexes $m,n$ mean.

Please, what is the right Frobenius canonical form?